# Is there a way to return integers separated by space from a function whose return type is int?

Tags: integer

so I took this OA for an interview and one of the questions was:

given an input of a bunch of integers, sum them up and return those input integers that the sum isn't divisible by.

For example if our input is:

1 2 3 4 5
our output should be 2 4, since the sum is 15 and 1 3 and 5 can divide 15.

The issue was the return type of the function in which I had to write this was int, and I was supposed to return all the integers separated by space. An array or tuple of the integers would not satisfy the requirement.

Any help? I could choose any language to solve this so it's not a language specific question.

Comment: Choose a language like python that doesn't have returns types, so you can just return a vector.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think most languages allow for non-int characters to be returned in the int data type. Perhaps use 0 instead of space so in this case return 204.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to print them with “for” cycle on one line separated with space.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).